# how to verify text present in placeholder in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to verify the text present in placeholder. I have located the element and i am using Assert text command. I've entered the same string in value. On executing it is showing actual value did not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `assertAttribute` or `verifyAttribute` command.

**Example:**

```
verifyAttribute | css=#search@placeholder |  Sample String
```

**Notes:**

- In the Target column of Selenium IDE, you need to provide the proper path of the element followed by an **@** sign
  and then the name of the attribute. (placeholder in your case)
- Using
  `verifyAttibute` will still continue running the test case once an
  error is detected while using `assertAttribute` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @Rodel Bernal

Comment: @dave
 It would be appreciated if you could at least accept my answer by clicking the check button. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that *assertText* function can only check static text on your webpage.

You must be getting an error message.
This is perfectly normal.

What can help in this situation is using the *assertAttribute* or *verifyAttribute* functions.

Both these functions perform the same task; the former stops the test after receiving an error message in the text box while verifyValue just records the error in the log and runs the next commands.

While giving the target, either specify the XPath or refer by using the **name=*name*@placeholder** format.

You can find the ***name*** value by inspecting the box with a firefox addon called Firepath which runs with another firefox tool called Firebug. Install them if you don't already have.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Xpath contains() is the best way.

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@placeholder,"email")]')

Format : '//tag[contains(@attribute,"value")]'